# onLongClick for plain text inside of a WebView

Tags: android, webview, onlongclicklistener

I am building an app that contains a WebView which will be used to show the user some links and some plain text. I want to make it so that the user can LongClick on a link, or a body of text and get the option to delete that thing from the html thats being shown in the WebView. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449098/enable-longclick-in-webview) got me half way there. LongClicking on the links works by using the wv.getHitTestResult() method. But now my problem is when I long click on plain text the onLongClick() method of the listener doesn't get called, and even if it did getHitTestResult() would not return the text that the user is touching(I tried setting an onTouchListener to see if getHitTestResult().getExtra() had a value when I touched plain text)

So my questions is does anyone know how I can get LongClick events inside of a WebView that are on text that is not Linkified?(I assume this is possible some how because that is how I can select text in the default browser). and once I get the LongClick event how can I get access to which body of text was clicked?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this, there are a lot of unanswered questions in the Android tag and we are trying to clear them up, if you have a solution please post it and accept

Comment: Nope never found anything. My fix was to stop displaying in WebView.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I am too facing this problem, onLongClick() is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer here ,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908125/1503130

Also if you have any other fix to the problem then do share it.