# Web-view full-screen mode

Tags: android

i have set swf  file in `webview` i got everything is successfully but when i long press it give me option of full-screen so i need to avoid it how can i do that ??

**here i have attach image :**

[image]

Here is my **webview** :

```
wv_introduction = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ady_solwv);
                wv_introduction.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                wv_introduction.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                wv_introduction.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                wv_introduction.loadUrl(str_url);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449098/enable-longclick-in-webview

Comment: i have try this but it not help me

Comment: Is your problem that its not fullscreen or that it gives a popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these:

```
wv_introduction.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
wv_introduction.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have also tryed but get failure