# How to Make Long-Pressing Links in WebView Trigger Link Like Normal?

Tags: android, android-webview

In a regular browser, long-pressing a link causes a context menu to appear. I understand why this doesn't happen in a WebView and I'm fine with a content menu not appearing. What I would like to have happen instead, though, is have the long-press trigger the link just as though the link was tapped on like normal. Currently, long-pressing links does nothing at all. What can I do to make it so that long-pressing links triggers them like normal?

My code:

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.UUID;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageView mSplashScreen;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mSplashScreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);

        mSplashScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webview.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSplashScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can simply by enabling the WebView to behave that way for each of its links, but there was a suggested alternative approach to take within this particular suggestion.
[long press within webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449098/enable-longclick-in-webview)